# Does a Google Compute Engine instance sleep?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want to use SparkleShare to sync files between computers so I'm looking for a way to have git repositories online to hold the files.

I'm looking at using Google Compute Engine to host them. It would be a lot cheaper if I only paid for the time I'm actually doing a sync.

Does a Google Compute Engine instance sleep (with respect to billing) when not in use, or do I have to pay for it 24/7 to use it at all?

Comment: What did you end up doing? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: @cs_pupil I didn't end up using Google compute engine for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start and stop instances. From the docs:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/instances/stop

> Stops a running instance, shutting it down cleanly, and allows you to
>   restart the instance at a later time. Stopped instances do not incur
>   per-minute, virtual machine usage charges while they are stopped, but
>   any resources that the virtual machine is using, such as persistent
>   disks and static IP addresses, will continue to be charged until they
>   are deleted.

Comment: Updated link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/stop